# Python - run script at every specific MINUTE time of the day

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, datetime

I need to run a python script at specific time at EVERY minutes. I CANNOT use time.sleep to wait 60 second for it, because my script takes 8-10 seconds to run, （60 + 8 = 68 or 60+10 = 70）
I need to run the script at below specific time through out the day.

```
2023-01-09 01:01:05
2023-01-09 01:02:05
2023-01-09 01:03:05
2023-01-09 01:04:05
2023-01-09 01:05:05
```

I do lots of search and can't find a good answer. Worse case should i create a dataframe to tell the script based on the time?

besides, in window Task Scheduler,I don't see there's a option to set 1 Minute recurring.

thanks

Comment: use TaskManager if you are in Windows or Cron if you are on Linux.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki do you refer to Task Scheduler? I don't see there's a option for my to set 1 Minute recurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the time when it should next run and then do:

```
time.sleep(nextime - datetime.now())
```